# document.all["" + object.getAttribute("EndDate", true) + ""].value; do not work in firefox

Tags: javascript

`document.all["" + object.getAttribute("EndDate", true) + ""].value;`

does work in firefox but work in IE.

what is the alternative way other than the code above to work in multiple browsers?

Comment: Check out something called the W3C DOM, I heard it's pretty cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the element by it's id use this form:

```
document.getElementById("elemen_id");
```

[`document.all`](http://simonwillison.net/2003/Aug/11/documentAll/) isn't cross browser.

If you want to get an element's attribute use:

```
element.getAttribute("EndDate");
```

you don't need the `.value` property for that.
The second parameter of [`getAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536429(VS.85).aspx) is not a boolean, rather an integer, and is only used in rare cases (like getting an element's href in IE). If you want *case-sensitivity* use 1, but *true* here is a bit confusing of what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

`document.all` is a thing of the past and should be avoided . It is used to support IE4 ( which no one uses now a days ) . So unless you need to support IE4 , I think you should go ahead with `document.getElementById` which is supported by all browsers .

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `document.all` as it's non-standard. `document.getElementById` is the way to go.